# In Zend framework, where should I put the custom validator?

Tags: zend-framework

I put the class under
application\validate\PasswordConfirmation.php

And it doesn't work.

Error
Class 'Default_Validate_PasswordConfirmation' not found

still occurs.

Does anyone have this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question:

I add the validator successfully according to this post: 
[Where should My_Validate_PasswordConfirmation put in Zend framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010265/where-should-myvalidatepasswordconfirmation-put-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 1):

I usually place them at `/library/CV/Validate/`

Example:

```
/library/CV/Validate/EmpresaNueva.php:
class CV_Validate_EmpresaNueva extends Zend_Validate_Abstract {
    //Validator code
}
```

Where library is the place where you have Zend.

Content of index.php @ /public:

```
$root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));

set_include_path($root.'/application' . PATH_SEPARATOR
    .$root.'/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR
    . get_include_path()
);
```

Comment: I try to place the file under library/My/Validate/PasswordConfirmation.php. But the Class "'Default_Validate_PasswordConfirmation' not found" still occurs. Do I miss any steps?

Comment: I try to place the file under library/Default/Validate/PasswordConfirmation.php

Comment: Check the edit. library/ es where Zend folder is placed. Don't know where you have yours.

Answer (score 1):

For customer validators, you need to put them in a location that is on your include path.  Also, you need to add your validator to make it available using `Zend_Validate::addValidator()`.

See the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html) for more information.

Comment: I add the validator successfully according to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010265/where-should-myvalidatepasswordconfirmation-put-in-zend-framework